# How can I implement a query comparing ID's in different sheets with printing of confirmation in corresponding line?

Tags: excel, vba

Let's assume I have a workbook with 2 worksheets.(There are more but this doesn't matter for the question)
Sheet 1 and Sheet 2 each hold 2 columns that look like this:

Sheet 1:   ID                      Open job

Sheet 2:    …                            ID

I would like to check if the ID in Sheet 1 in the first row can be found anywhere in the second column in Sheet 2. If the ID is found, the application should print "YES" in the first respectively the corresponding line of the original search-ID under "Open job"; if the ID is not found,"NO" should be printed.

Since I'm new to coding I don't really have a clue how to get this done.
I have a structure of pseudo-code and some "real" elements for better problem understanding.

Here is the pseudo code:

```
Sub Query_if_ID_matches_print_YES/NO

    'Lets assume there are headers in the first line of both worksheets'

    For each Cell in Sheets ("Sheet1").Range("A2:A500")

        If Cell("A2").Value = Value 'Should be an integer' 

           Search for Value in ("Sheet2").Range("B2:B500")
               If Value found in ("Sheet2").Range("B2:B500")
                   Print Value = "YES" in Sheets ("Sheet1").Range("B2")
               Else Print Value = "NO" in Sheets ("Sheet1").Range("B2")
               End If
        Next Cell
     End for
 End Sub
```

I hope I stated the problem in an understandable way.
Thanks for any help in advance:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understood your question correctly this might work:

```
Sub Query()
Dim wks1 As Worksheet
Dim wks2 As Worksheet
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim objDic As Object

    Set wks1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set wks2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Set rng1 = wks1.Range("A2:A500")
    Set rng2 = wks2.Range("B2:B500")
    Set objDic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    For Each rng In rng2
        If objDic.Exists(rng.Value) = False Then
            objDic.Add rng.Value, rng.Address
        End If
    Next rng
    For Each rng In rng1
        If objDic.Exists(rng.Value) Then
            rng.Offset(0, 1).Value = "YES"
        Else
            rng.Offset(0, 1).Value = "NO"
        End If
    Next rng
    Set objDic = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Works perfectly fine!
Thank you very much.